# IdentityServer4 (3.0.0) exception adding OpenIdConnect

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, .net-core-3.0

When I call AddOpenIdConnect(), I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RequestPathBaseCookieBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions..ctor()

**Example Code:**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {           
            services.AddMvc();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                    options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/...";
                    options.ClientId = "client_id";
                    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-aad");
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-aad");
                    options.RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-aad");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role"
                    };
                });
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to protect an API that is co-located inside your Identity service?  If so then have a look at this http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html.

Comment: No, I am not. There is no API co-located here. I am just trying to get a functional IS 3.0.0 running in a POC project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an updated nuget reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (now it's at 3.3.1).

This DLL only targets netcore, so you will have to change the TargetFramework from netstandard to netcoreapp.

Which sucks, but I do not believe there is any other option.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the cookie [Adding User Authentication with OpenID Connect](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

Comment: It still throws that error. It seems there is an issue with dependencies on 3.0.0

Comment: Steps to repro:

1.  ```dotnet new is4aspid -n ErrorIn30```

2.  Update to core 3.0 in project

3.  Update packages

4.  Add OpenIdConnect in startup configure services

5.  Debug

Comment: I followed your repro steps with SDK 3.0.100-rc1-014190 and did not reproduce the error when deugging.